How do I resolve a temporary failure in name resolution error?
I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, on a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor running on a Windows subsystem (WSL2). When I try to run the command sudo apt install bzip2, I get the error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package bzip2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bzip2' has no installation candidate

The next thing I tried was:
sudo apt update
and then
sudo apt install bzip2 which ran into the same error.
The next thing I tried was :
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update

Which ran into the same problem when trying to install bzip2. The next thing I did was to try manually installing bzip2 with:
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bzip2/bzip2_1.0.8-5build1_amd64.deb

Which returns the error:
--2024-08-31 18:02:48--  http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bzip2/bzip2_1.0.8-5build1_amd64.deb
Resolving mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘mirrors.kernel.org

The next thing I did was checking the internet connection by pinging google, and I get the error:
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
So I tried:
net stop LxssManager
net start LxssManager

Which also did not do anything. I then tried adding
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

To /etc/wsl.conf which did not do anything either.
The issue seems to be a DNS error, but am I not quite sure how to proceed form here.

I am now able to ping websites after I entered the commands:
sudo chown root:root /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/resolv.conf
But now I run into the original bzip2 has no installation candidate error.

I was able to install bzip2 through manual installation. This was only after inputting:
 sudo chown root:root /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo chmod 644 /etc/resolv.conf

And adding a public server to the resolv.conf file.
